# How to acquire a unique IP address

Tags: ip, database

How do I assign a unique IP address for my remote server? I am using windows 7 Operating System. Any other security configurations and recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Call your ISP and Pay for a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to speak to whoever looks after the network at the remote location, there's really no other way.